# Update of UITableView when tab is re-entered

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm making an application from a TabBarController (storyboard template). The tabs are all UINavigationControllers with UITableViews. Each time Tab 2 is entered the tableview should update (look for new items to add), but it only loads once! (First time tab is entered.) How to do this?

A closer description of my issue:

When I'm in Tab 1, I select some cells (objects) to add to the TableView in Tab 2. Cell tap is changing a boolean for the reprecented object in a plist of objects.

So if I select objects in Tab 1 at launch, and then enter Tab 2, this TableView is filled with the cells because it's the first time I enter Tab 2 and it loads.

But if I go back to Tab 1 and select some more objects, these objects are not displayed in Tab 2 because the TableView is already loaded. So how to reload the Tab 2 TableView? Should I do this when the selection of tab 2 is happening? I have no class or reference for TabBarController, it's in storyboard only. Or maybe should I do it in the addObject action in Tab 1? Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try add

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

in the `viewWillAppear` of Tab 2 view controller.

Comment: Tried to, but made no difference. Can placement of -(void)viewWillAppear in .m affect its function?

Comment: If you mean the .m file of Tab 2 view controller, it is in the right place. Does you use the default UITableViewController implementation for Tab 2? If not, try replace self.tableView with any reference of the table view you made.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear
{
    [super viewDidAppear];
    [self.tableViewName reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use notifications. Send local NSNotification and then addObserver on your tableView view to respond and reload. Reloading the table in the normal manner will not work as the view has already been loaded.